# Regular expression and number with last two letters in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have code that I want to get out of the string. The problem I have is that the texts can be of different lengths ranging from 8 characters to the 18 character, but some also have "SE" at the end.

```
enter code here
String String1 = "Hello 213123123SE world";
String String2 = "Hello 888888888 World"
```

and then i have now i can only take numbers in all length

```
 string regexp = @"[^\d$]";
```

(i will output see out here)OutPut:

"213123123SE"
"888888888"

I want both to have only numbers and numbers with "SE" at the end

Comment: What do you want to extract from those two strings? only number?

Comment: Will they only have SE? No other letters at the end?

Comment: NO, only number first but and will have number with SE

Comment: From your other questions, it seems you are misusing Stack Overflow as a free crowdsourcing device, i.e. it looks like you are looking for code-monkey-robots. Please, instead of spamming more questions, read some material on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

If I have interpreted your question correctly, try this: `[\d]{8,18}(SE)?`

(You can try it out here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ unfortunately the Share Link feature isn't working)

Comment: output: "\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n8450418\r\n\r\nSO337389\r\n\r\n" 

Can i delte \r\n in regexp?

Comment: oh, my array is so loong. my goal is call number > 10 and <18 and number with SE

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what the issue is. If you provide some test data I can help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want number that end with SE then you can use `[\d]{8,18}(SE){1}`

and you can use [expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) it useful for regex test and tutorial

and if you wan only the number from returned value you can use `result.Replace("SE","");`