# Regexp find the number with start number 8

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My problem is that I'm about to build a function that retrieves a PDF document and print the document I want to pick up a Specified numbers starting with `8`.

Input:

```
"hello world, the number I want call is 84553741. help me plz."
```

Regexp:

```
 String[] result = Regex.Split(Result, @"[^\d$]");
```

How can I find number start with number `8`?

Comment: Even though there are answers by now, I would advise to read some more material on the topic. You seem to not have realised yet that you can match literal values, and do not _have_ to use those special patterns.

Comment: Okay, seriously. I hereby revoke my answer, even though it was upvoted already, because I want you to read actual learning material on regular expressions. From your other questions, it seems you are misusing Stack Overflow as a free crowdsourcing device, i.e. it looks like you are looking for code-monkey-robots (robots, because real code monkeys at least need bananas). Please, instead of spamming more questions, read some material on the topic.

Comment: Duplicate of [Regular expression and number with last two letters in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038034/regular-expression-and-number-with-last-two-letters-in-c-sharp). Please keep it to one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will extract all numbers starting with 8 from the supplied input string.

```
var input= "hello world, the number i want call is 84553741. help me plz.";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<!\d)8\d*");
IEnumerable<String> numbers = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Value);
foreach(var number in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Comment: How can i call value in numbers?

Comment: @MaxTorstensson This answer **does not** match numbers that **start** with `8`, as it could also match `128`. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Good catch! In the interests of correctness I've updated my answer with your negative lookbehind. @MaxTorstensson : feel free to accept Nolonar's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The two answers already available do not actually match numbers that **start** with 8, but numbers that **contain** 8. The match, however will start with 8.

To only match numbers that start with 8, you need this Regex:

```
string[] testArray = new string[] { "test888", "test181", "test890", "test8" };
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<!\d)8\d*");

foreach (string testString in testArray)
{
    if (regex.IsMatch(testString))
        Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" matches: {1}", testString, regex.Match(testString));
    else
        Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" doesn't match", testString);
}
```

The output would be:

```
"test888" matches: 888
"test181" doesn't match
"test890" matches: 890
"test8" matches: 8
```

Using the Regex `"8\d*"` would yield following results:

```
"test888" matches: 888 // not mentioned results: 88 and 8
"test181" matches: 81  // obviously wrong
"test890" matches: 890
"test8" matches: 8
```